# Mocking a generic RestTemplate with Mockito 2 stubs the arguments as null or an empty string

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, resttemplate

Here is my stubbing code.  The exchange method is called with the proper parameters (shown below the stubbing code) but for some reason, the `when().then()` statement is looking for null parameters.  Why is the `PotentialStubbingProblem` exception being thrown here?

```
@BeforeEach
public <T> void configureMocks() {
    when(apiAccess.getKey()).thenReturn("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    when(apiAccess.getUrlPrefix()).thenReturn("{region}.api.riotgames.com");
    val response = new ResponseEntity<Collection<T>>(HttpStatus.OK);
    when(restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
            ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
            (HttpEntity<?>) isNull(),
            eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Collection<T>>() {})))
            .thenReturn(response);
}
```

`PotentialStubbingProblem` output is shown belown:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'exchange' method:
    restTemplate.exchange(
    https://JP1.api.riotgames.com/lol/champion-mastery/v3/champion-masteries/by-summoner/1234567890?api_key=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,
    GET,
    null,
    ParameterizedTypeReference<java.util.Collection<T>>
);
    -> at org.eyeoftheherald.riotapiinterface.service.RiotApiService.getEntityList(RiotApiService.java:176)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. restTemplate.exchange("", null, null, null);
```

`ApiAccess` is shown below:

```
@Configuration
public class RiotApiInterfaceConfiguration {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:configuration.properties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "api-access")
    public static class ApiAccess {
        private String key;
        private String urlPrefix;
    }

    @Autowired
    public RiotApiInterfaceConfiguration() {
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `apiAccess`?

Comment: `apiAccess` is a spring configuration class, I'll post the source in the OP

Comment: Note that there is an interface `RestOperations` that is easier to mock specifically for this case.

Comment: I've never seen that interface, I'll do some research on it.  How would I mock out an exchange call from its implemented interface? OH kind of vital piece of information but if I haven't made it clear -- this is a unit test :)

Comment: 1) What do your actual invocations look like? 2) Do you have multiple stubbings defined for that method? 3) Did you mean `any` instead of `eq` within the following definition `eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Collection<T>>() {}))`?

Comment: 1) My actual invocation is inside the `PotentialStubbingProblem` log -- with the long url starting with `JP1`
2) No, which is why I'm confused :(
3) That's interesting... on second thought I should have used `any`... I'll try it as I get back!  One question though -- would it cause the stubbing to be looking for `"", null, null, null`?